# How to use SQL dense_rank and use original indexing

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to generate a query with an ordered ranking of duplicates. For example if I have the following table

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3
---+------+------+------
1  |  3   |  a   |  x 
2  |  2   |  a   |  y 
3  |  1   |  b   |  y
4  |  2   |  c   |  z 
5  |  3   |  a   |  x 
6  |  3   |  a   |  x
7  |  2   |  a   |  y
```

My desired output would be:

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3 | rank
---+------+------+------+-----
1  |  3   |  a   |  x   |  1
2  |  2   |  a   |  y   |  2
3  |  1   |  b   |  y   |  3
4  |  2   |  c   |  z   |  4
5  |  3   |  a   |  x   |  1
6  |  3   |  a   |  x   |  1
7  |  2   |  a   |  y   |  2
```

Where the all rows that are equal across the columns are similarly ranked and the ranking starts from 1 in the original order.

I have tried

```sql
SELECT
      id
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col1, col2, col2) AS rank
FROM
    test_table;
```

but what I get is

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3 | rank
---+------+------+------+-----
1  |  3   |  a   |  x   |  4
2  |  2   |  a   |  y   |  2
3  |  1   |  b   |  y   |  1
4  |  2   |  c   |  z   |  3
5  |  3   |  a   |  x   |  4
6  |  3   |  a   |  x   |  4
7  |  2   |  a   |  y   |  2
```

Where the rank count is based off the `ORDER BY` in the query and I can't figure out how to change this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no built in way to do this, but you can use a sub query to achieve your result

```
SELECT temp.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rank_id)
FROM ( 
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, min(id) AS rank_id 
  FROM temp
  GROUP BY col1, col2, col3 
) pg_sucks JOIN temp USING (col1, col2, col3)
ORDER BY id;
```

Here is what I did (ignore the bad names, its 23:30 here if it makes it more redeemable)

The sub query finds all the present `col1/2/3` combinations and assigns them their lowest ranked id, from there we link those columns with the outer query ones and we do a `dense_rank` sort based on the `rank_id`, oh and also sort them by id so we get them in order.

Feel free to play with it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/if1t8r5wrQUMSTQYYTtnwn/1)

Also as a footnote you dont need to give a table allias since pgSQL-16, so if you are running that omit pg_sucks

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change to `ORDER BY` of the `DENSE_RANK`:

```
SELECT
      id, col1, col2, col3
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col2, col1 desc, col2) AS rank
FROM
    test_table
ORDER BY id
  ;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/k7j6wZy_)

Comment: The following query will produce the correct results for _this_ example dataset only and any minor change will make it meaningless. It assumes the the ranking should be done from col2 ASC and col1 DESC (the last col2 is useless) this happens to coincide with the ordering of id but it is just a coincidence.